# Adding two exact same table on qlikview and avoid qlik to merge/discard table

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a problem on adding two tables to the qlikview. Currently, I need to add multiple tables from excel data in qlikview, to avoid circular reference. I have tried to add it multiple times, but qlikview always merge the table, or even discard one, because it contains same data.

How to add two exact same table in qlikview?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- [NoConcatenate](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/NoConcatenate.htm) - using this prefix before loading table "forces" QV/QS no not concatenate this table to the other table(s) having the same set of columns. This will keep the field names as it is and you will get `synthetic key` between the tables (if dont drop/change them by the end of the script
- [Qualify](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Qualify.htm) - this prefix will load the following table and will change the field names in format `TableName.FieldName`.

For example:

```
Qualify *;
  MyTable:
  Load
    Id,
    Value
  From 
    MyCSV.csv (txt)
  ;
UnQualify *;
```

Will result in `MyTable` with 2 fields - `MyTable.Id` and `MyTable.Value`

When using `Qualify` dont forget to call `UnQualify` when you dont need more tables to be qualified!

You can have `Qualify` and non-qualified fields using:

```
Qualify *;
UnQualify Id;
  MyTable:
  Load
    Id,
    Value
  From 
    MyCSV.csv (txt)
  ;
UnQualify *;
```

Will result in `MyTable` with 2 fields - `Id` and `MyTable.Value`

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `noconcatenate load` (instead of just `load`) then it will load the data in twice. However watch out as you'll end up with one big synthetic key if you do that without making sure the field names are different in the two tables. Either use `qualify` or set your field names in one or both tables to be different.